# Variable range and keep getting "method range of object _worksheet failed"

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and I know similar questions have been asked but I cant seem to find the answer. I just want to have a variable range to allow the macro to go through all values one by one down the list, but it keeps giving me the same error. also, i want to compare all the numbers in a certain range and pick the first value that is more than another value (all in the same row). i dont know if i'm doing it right, the code is here:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim buysignal As Variant
Dim OHLC As Variant
Dim ffdhigh As Variant
Dim i As Long

Sheets("sheet2").Activate
Set buysignal = Range("M" & i).Value
OHLC = Range("B" & i & ":" & "E" & i).Value
ffdhigh = Range("I" & i).Value

For i = 63 To 150
If OHLC > ffdhigh Then
buysignal = "buy"
Else: buysignal = ""

End If
Next i

End Sub
```

error message : Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_worksheet' failed

Thanks guys, any input will be very appreciated.

Comment: Which Range-method fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `i` does not have a value yet, and you are using it to set the `buysignal` range. So, set `i` to a value.

Next, the same line will throw an error because you use `set` to set the value of an object, but you set it to the value of a cell. That's a type mismatch.

Plan what you want to do before you start coding. Oh, and don't use variants for everything. It is asking for the kind of trouble you're facing now. Properly type your variables, then you will catch type mismatches right away.

Comment: HI, thanks for the comment. does that mean I need to state an initial value first for i despite my 'for' function?

Comment: You use `i` before the `for` loop. It needs a value when it is first used. Just look at your code.

Comment: thanks! I've edited my code to attach "i" to a value, and edited my variables to ranges and then used .value instead. Now, my If OHLC.value > ffdhigh.value gives the error "type mismatch". how do i solve this? do you need me to retype my new code in the question? thanks so much.

Comment: @jadeliew123 `OHLC` is a `Variant` and you're assigning it to `Range("B" & i & ":E" & i)`, whatever the value of `i` is - `OHLC` is therefore a 2D variant array. Then you have `ffdhigh = Range("I" & i).Value` - `ffdhigh` is a value of whatever the type of the value in that cell is. If Excel sees it as a date, you'll have a variant/`Date`; if it's a numeric, you'll have a variant/`Double`; if it's `TRUE` then you have a variant/`Boolean`, etc. You can't compare a *range of values* with one single value. It's not clear what `If OHLC > ffdhigh` is supposed to even mean.

Comment: hi @Mat'sMug, I understand what you're saying, and I'm trying to change my code such that i want to compare the values within that 2D variant dimensional range to another single value. I've edited my code above, and have used ranges instead of variants, but i still get the error "object variable or with block variable not set." why is this so?

Comment: @jadeliew123 you've just invalidated this answer with that edit. Please avoid *chameleonizing* your question - this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. You ask a specific question, you get a specific answer *to that question*. You can't just change your question every time you get a new answer. Runtime error 91 is explained in hundreds of places on this site.